# How to pass a string from PHP to a CGI script

Tags: php

I have a PHP script and this script calls a CGI script at the end. How to pass a variable or a string from PHP sccipt to CGI script called?

PHP script:

```
<?php
$string="Hello";
passthru ('/var/www/cgi-bin/hello.cgi');
?>
```

Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
....
print "$string"
exit(0)
```

When I run the php script, it should display "Hello" within cgi script.
Thanks

Comment: Does this Perl script actually need to function as a CGI script, invoked directly by the web server, or is this PHP script the *only* way that it will be invoked? And is this parameter something the Perl script already expects to receive in some way (presumably via CGI environment variables) or a new requirement?

Comment: CGI script runs an IDL code and IDL code produces some flags or variables that I need them in PHP. Of course, I can write them to a file and then I can read that file from php. But I am wondering the shortest and direct way, such as IPC process.

Comment: That comment doesn't answer my question - I'm asking whether you can change how the script runs, and e.g. pass it command line arguments, rather than it being a CGI script. On the other hand, you now seem to be talking about getting values *out* of the script, but your original question was about passing them *into* it.

Comment: I have to use the php script which is actually a web page including a form. But I have to use only  "POST" option in form submit. I don't want to use "GET" option to pass variables as arguments to CGI script. Instead, I want to catch some variable/string produced in php from CGI script (just like example in my question). Is that clear?